# Updating file in S3 bucket. Still getting '304 - Not modified'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a setup consisting of a S3 bucket containing a single ZIP file which is updated regularly. I have set up a cloudfront to make it available via https.

It works just fine, as in I get the file if I request the url. However, the response returns with a "304 - Not modified". I have tried to rename the file and to upload a new file to replace the old one. It still says "304 - Not modified".

I have tried to fiddle around with the Edge cache settings on the CloudFront behavior page. No luck, always just returns "304..."

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is a cache, so if you update a file in S3, CloudFront will not immediately see that, and will still respond to clients with a 304 as long as the old version didn't expire yet.

You can look up how to configure the expiration here: [Managing How Long Content Stays in an Edge Cache (Expiration)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

And you can also force a cache-update by creating an invalidation: [Invalidating Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I tried to set the TTL to 0 and 1, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same concern, did the hard refresh which resolved the issue and loaded the new s3 scripts.

To do hard refresh in windows chrome , use below command:

```
ctrl+shift+r
```